# Psycopg error when using register_type() with Newrelic agent

Tags: python, psycopg2, newrelic

When using Psycopg's `register_type()` function while having Newrelic's agent initialized, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: argument 2 must be a connection, cursor or None
```

because the cursor is being wrapped at runtime with the `newrelic.hooks.database_psycopg2.CursorWrapper` class.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've found to avoid this issue is to use `register_json()` instead of `register_type()`. When all arguments are provided it doesn't really have any JSON-specific logic, contrary to what the name may suggest.

For example, the following snippet will raise `TypeError: argument 2 must be a connection, cursor or None`
when used with Newrelic's agent:

```py
from psycopg2.extensions import register_type, new_type, new_array_type

numeric_type = new_type((1700,), "DEC2FLOAT",  lambda v, _: float(v) if v is not None else None)
register_type(numeric_type, cursor)

numeric_array_type = new_array_type((1231,), "DEC2FLOATARRAY", numeric_type)
register_type(numeric_array_type, cursor)
```

While this snippet won't raise the error and will produce an equivalent result:

```py
from psycopg2.extras import register_json

register_json(
    cursor,
    globally=False,
    loads=float,
    oid=1700,
    array_oid=1231,
    name="DEC2FLOAT",
)
```

I'm not really sure why one works and the other doesn't. The internal implementation of the `register_json` function uses practically the same code as the first snippet, so I'm guessing it's due to some import order shenanigans.